Getting error while reading data from elasticsearch 7.10 using Spark 3.x
Spark 3.x
Elasticsearch: 7.10
Spark config:
.config("spark.kubernetes.executor.container.image", "itayb/spark:3.1.1-hadoop-3.2.0-aws") \
.config("spark.jars.packages", "org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-spark-30_2.12:7.12.0,org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.17,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.2.0,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:3.2.0,com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bundle:1.11.975,org.postgresql:postgresql:42.7.3") \
.config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "/opt/hadoop/hadoop-aws-3.2.0.jar:/opt/hadoop/aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.975.jar") \
.config("spark.executor.extraClassPath", "/opt/hadoop/hadoop-aws-3.2.0.jar:/opt/hadoop/aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.975.jar") \

Error:
    coding: java.lang.RuntimeException: scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JListWrapper is not a valid external type for schema of string
if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 0, avg_rating), FloatType) AS avg_rating#209
if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 1, category), StringType), true, false) AS category#210
if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 2, country), StringType), true, false) AS country#211
if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeUtils$, TimestampType, fromJavaTimestamp, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 3, created_date), TimestampType), true, false) AS created_date#212

I have explicit casting and even gave a default value:
dataframe1 = dataframe1.na.fill({
    "avg_rating": 0.0,
    "num_ratings": 0,
    "num_reviews": 0,
    "product_url": ""
})

I can read the data, but when I try to apply a filter, it fails:
# Filter the DataFrame based on the product_url
filtered_df = dataframe1.filter(dataframe1.product_url == 'https://www.carrefourksa.com/mafsau/en/cup-noodles/indomie-cup-noodle-beef-60g/p/26647')

# Show the filtered DataFrame without truncating the values
filtered_df.show(truncate=False)

